# valid way to calculate angle between 2 CLLocations?

Tags: coordinates, core-location, augmented-reality, angle

Is this a valid way to calculate an angle (in radians) from one CLLocation to another?

```
-(float)angleFromLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)start toLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)end {
float deltaX = start.latitude - end.latitude;
float deltaY = start.longitude - end.longitude;
float ang = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

return ang;}
```

Please advise!

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're getting close. Check out the solutions to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140045/how-to-get-degree-of-poi-from-another-poi

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 version:

```
extension FloatingPoint {

    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
       
    func heading(to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {
        let lat1 = self.latitude.degreesToRadians
        let lon1 = self.longitude.degreesToRadians

        let lat2 = to.latitude.degreesToRadians
        let lon2 = to.longitude.degreesToRadians

        let dLon = lon2 - lon1
        let y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
        let x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon)

        let headingDegrees = atan2(y, x).radiansToDegrees
        if headingDegrees >= 0 {
            return headingDegrees
        } else {
            return headingDegrees + 360
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly as I used extension function directly in class because In extension I'm getting this error: Implementation of 'Equatable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type

Comment: Your code work perfectly. Please add some explanation to your code that help in understanding. Thank you

Comment: This worked great, `Equatable` is not needed though, and throws an error in later versions of Swift. I tried editing the answer but there are currently too many pending edits.

Answer (score 3):

I used a variant of this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925942/cllocation-category-for-calculating-bearing-w-haversine-function) and it works well:

```
double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;};
double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) {return radians * 180.0/M_PI;};

- (double)bearingFromLocation:(CLLocation *)fromLocation toLocation:(CLLocation *)toLocation
{

    double lat1 = DegreesToRadians(fromLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    double lon1 = DegreesToRadians(fromLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    double lat2 = DegreesToRadians(toLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    double lon2 = DegreesToRadians(toLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    double dLon = lon2 - lon1;

    double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
    double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
    double radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

    double degreesBearing = RadiansToDegrees(radiansBearing);

    if (degreesBearing >= 0) {
        return degreesBearing;
    } else {
        return degreesBearing + 360.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am tracking the user's location based on GPS readings. The GPS reading gives me a "course" value, which determines the direction due north in degrees. When I calculate the difference of angle between two coordinates, things get ugly if the user moves from 0 to 359 degree. In real time, it could have been a 1 degree change, but my code is giving 359 degree change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The best method I found for this computation was to use the Spherical Law of Cosines. There is a C function to do this available [here on github](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/blob/master/Utils/UtilitiesGeo.h) called headingInDegrees.  It takes two lat/long pairs and returns heading:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
* Given two lat/lon points on earth, calculates the heading 
* from lat1/lon1 to lat2/lon2.   
*  
* lat/lon params in degrees 
* result in degrees 
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
double headingInDegrees(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2);
```

Since a CLLocationCoordinate2d contains latitude and longitude, it is easy to pass those two fields to this function and get the heading back.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems using the given answer where there were certain locations which would give the wrong result. My solution is based off https://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/distance.php#txtDist_3

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {


func getRadiansFrom(degrees: Double ) -> Double {

    return degrees * .pi / 180

}

func getDegreesFrom(radians: Double) -> Double {

    return radians * 180 / .pi

}

public func bearing(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {

    let lat1 = self.getRadiansFrom(degrees:self.latitude)
    let long1 = self.getRadiansFrom(degrees:self.longitude)
    let lat2 = self.getRadiansFrom(degrees:location.latitude)
    let long2 = self.getRadiansFrom(degrees:location.longitude)
    

    let deltaLat = log(tan(lat2/2 + .pi/4)/tan(lat1/2 + .pi/4))
    var deltaLong = (long2-long1)
    
    if(deltaLong > .pi){
        deltaLong = (long1-long2)
    }
    
    return self.getDegreesFrom(radians: atan2(deltaLong, deltaLat))
}
```

}