# Get the bearing with direction between 2 geographic coordinates

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have 2 sets of coordinates. The user has to travel from one location to the other. What would be the best means to show directions between the 2 coordinates. I have calculated the distance between 2 points. 
I have also found the angle between the 2 coordinates.

```
p1 = CGPointMake(coordinatesInDisplacement.latitude, coordinatesInDisplacement.longitude);
p2 = CGPointMake(coordinatesInDistance.latitude,coordinatesInDistance.longitude);

f = [self pointPairToBearingDegrees:p1 secondPoint:p2];

- (CGFloat) pointPairToBearingDegrees:(CGPoint)startingPoint secondPoint:(CGPoint) endingPoint
{
CGPoint originPoint = CGPointMake(endingPoint.x - startingPoint.x, endingPoint.y - startingPoint.y); // get origin point to origin by subtracting end from start
float bearingRadians = atan2f(originPoint.y, originPoint.x); // get bearing in radians
float bearingDegrees = bearingRadians * (180.0 / M_PI); // convert to degrees
bearingDegrees = (bearingDegrees > 0.0 ? bearingDegrees : (360.0 + bearingDegrees)); // correct discontinuity
return bearingDegrees;
}
```

Is finding angle without direction any use for navigation. Is finding direction, with the provided 2 coordinates only, possible?

But I think that wouldn't just be enough. What all details should I(or it is possible to) provide the user from IOS device to correctly reach from the starting point to the destination point.

Edit: I have 2 locations, one is in England and the other in Spain. If I am travelling from Spain to England,

1. is it possible to get directions like, 30°N 20°W. i.e. I have to travel 30°N 20°W from Spain to reach England.
2. Is the bearing angle, same as the angle in degrees I mentioned just above.

Comment: Hey @Xavi Valero check my answer.,

Comment: For two locations relatively close together near the Equator the conventional trig formula works well.  Farther from the Equator you must take into account that longitude lines are closer together than latitude lines.  For locations relatively far apart you must take into account the "great circle" phenomenon.

Comment: I got the idea of Bearing. But how can I integrate the direction part with it. Like 30°N?

Comment: @HotLicks In my case the locations would be pretty close. I have worked out the angle part as mentioned in my question. But still confused about the direction part like in 30°N.

Comment: For aircraft/boat navigation, the heading angle, relative to either true north or magnetic north, is essentially all you need.

Comment: @HotLicks You said "the heading angle, relative to either true north or magnetic north"
That's my question. How do I get the direction(north), here?

Comment: The lines of longitude run north-south.  I'm not entirely sure of the common lingo but I think an angle that's pointing 30 degrees east of the north-south line would be called "30 degrees north".  (I'm thinking that aircraft normally use 0-360, counting clock-wise from north, while sailors use a somewhat more arcane notation.)

Comment: (I assume you're not asking how you figure out what direction is north -- for that you use some sort of compass (or Polaris).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "heading/bearing" is the angle between a line pointing north and a line pointing where you are going. So if the target is directly north of you the heading is 0°. If the target is directly east of you the heading is 90°. Since the heading is always measured from north you don't say 90°N. If you have that as a measurement most geographers would think you meant [30° up from the equator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30th_parallel_north).

[Another question here on StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140045/how-to-get-angle-between-two-poi) shows an Objective-C implmentation of the Haversine formula. When near the equator you can use the faster formula and not be too wrong, but with the speed of iOS devices unless you are doing a million of these calculations you might as well use the more accurate one.

Comment: Thanks for giving a right idea about Bearing. Just out of curiosity, is there any other way to represent angle/direction between 2 points in the format of 30°N.

Comment: No. Firstly you can't have an angle between two points. Two points makes a line, not and angle. So you need a line to the north pole to compare your with. And since the north pole is the base that you always measure from the N in your measurement is not needed. You could say that one point is 30° north and 2° west of another point, but I've never seen anyone say measure one point to the next as 30°N

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate bearing angle between two lat, long by using haversine formula.

Follow this link for haversine formula which gives you distance, bearing, midpoint etc

[GeoCordinates](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)
[GeoCordinates Details](http://www.ig.utexas.edu/outreach/googleearth/latlong.html)